# Android, using Zxing into a webview, into back button, shows blank activity

Tags: android, webview, zxing, back-button

Okay, so I have an app that scans qr codes, verifies that it is a qr_code, and then opens the link stored in the code.  What I need help with is where to go from here as far as the back button.  When you push the back button it goes back to the app, which is fine, but it's a white screen (probably since there is nothing else that needs to be done after scan and webview creation).  I've looked at the android activity states and onResume, onStop, onPause, etc are triggered because of both the zxing barcode scanner and the new web activity.  I figured I could just set it up to where I start a new intent back to home page but then that wipes out the web activity.

```
        Intent goHome = new Intent(this, EActivity.class);

        if (scannedResult != null && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            if (scannedResult.getFormatName().equals("QR_CODE"))
            {
                Uri url = Uri.parse(scannedResult.getContents());

                WebView webview = new WebView(this);
                    setContentView(webview);

                Intent orrweb = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, url);
                    startActivity(orrweb);

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(NewScannerActivity.this, "Incorrect Barcode Type.  Please retry with QR Code.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    this.startActivity(goHome);
            }
        }
        else
        {
                this.startActivity(goHome);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.i("GMR", "error: " + e.toString());
    }
```